# pass string array out of function in c

Tags: c, arrays

I have a function that I'm using to build a string array. Inside the function i can print the array no worries however the program returns from the called function, the array (arr) remains NULL.
How do I get the data out of the array ?

Thanks.

```
main(){
  char **arr = NULL;
  funct(arr);
  printf("%s\n", arr[2];
}

funct(char **arr){
  arr = malloc(10*sizeof(char *));
  arr[1...n] = calloc(SIZE, sizeof(char));
  // Add data to array
}
```

Comment: if you're wanting to build a `char*[]` in the function, *including both the pointer array and its content*, you're missing a level of indirection on your input parameter, though honestly I don't see why you don't just *return* a `char**` and call it good.

Comment: I might do that... Is the only difference that it looks a little cleaner to do it that way? (I'm still learning). So that should fix the issue?

Comment: No, thats not the only difference. C is a by-value function-parameter language. If you want to modify something on the *caller's* side, the "value" you're passing needs to be an *address*, and the formal parameter needs to be a pointer-to type, dereferenced to write to the caller's var. If you have a pointer `p` and you're *not* dereferencing it at-assignment,  like `p = <<something>>` you're changing *nothing* on the caller side. In your case, `arr = malloc(...` allocates memory assigning the result to simply `arr`, and promptly leaks it on return.

Answer (score 2):

I can see several problemens in your code:

1. in the line   `printf("%s\n", arr[2];` you forgot a closing `)`
2. Your `arr` variable local to the `main` function is never initialized. In C, parameters are passed by value meaning that you are passing the `NULL` pointer to your function and inside this function, the local pointer `arr` is allocated but not the one of the `main` function.

The solution is to allocate the array in the `main` function and pass a pointer to the array and the size to the function that fills it:

```
main(){
  char **arr = malloc(10*sizeof(char *));
  funct(arr, 10);
  printf("%s\n", arr[2]);
}

funct(char **arr, int size){
  // Add data to array
  arr[0] = "first data";
  ....
  arr[size -1] = "last data";
}
```

Comment: Manuel thanks for your reply. My question is, if it's a pointer why am I not able to allocate memory to the pointer inside the function? What if inside the function I need to realoc?

Comment: @DangerousDave23 then either return the reallocated array as the function result or pass the pointer-to-pointer by address (yes, another level of indirection, a pointer-to pointer-to-pointer) and (shuddering to say this) join the three-star club. And yes, that name normally means you're probably doing something wrong (and thats a separate debate), but if you *know* how to use it, it works.